# Why my Path function is for Parent-Child is not working (Power BI)?

Tags: powerbi, dax, parent-child

I am getting a missing value error on the Path function in DAX. I know my Parent _ID columns only have few accounts. That because I only have few parent account with child relationship. 
Ultimately I want to show the Parent account with the child (with plus sing expansion)  and other accounts in the same list.

I also found the Power Bi Community post using "IF, LOOKUP VALUE, var function". It just gave me a blank column.

[image]

Any idea how should achieve my parent-child hierarchy? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the order of columns in function. ParentID should be the second one.

https://dax.guide/path/

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I did that still getting the same error. 
`Key = PATH('All Customers CSV'[ID],'All Customers CSV'[Parent_ID])`
Error - The value '' in 'All Customers CSV'[Parent_ID] must also exist in 'All Customers CSV'[ID]. Please add the missing data and try again.

Comment: are you sure that every Parent_ID is also in ID columns? Create a newTable with dax.
EXCEPT( ALL('All Customers CSV'[Parent_ID]), ALL('All Customers CSV'[ID]).

Check if you don't have for example white space at the end.

Comment: @masta42a, Thank you bring up that point, let me double-check the data and keep you posted. Again, thanks

Comment: I created a new Dax table and there is a blank raw.  I am completely lost here and not sure what to do. I also attached a link for my sample file. Please take a look if you have time. Thank you so much 
[Sample File Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dOPQU66MJek_i3VZa8HrWa5MOH0GAYwq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The problem is not with the blank, but with the remaining 16 instances. This means you have a parent_id that does not appear in the "All CSV Clients" [ID] column. You have to clear your data.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to get EXCEPT to work correctly.
Here is an example that uses NOT IN instead.

```
-- Create missing parents for PATH command
Missing assemblies = 
CALCULATETABLE(
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Item',
        'Item'[Item id],
        'Item'[Description],
        'Item'[Inventory],
        "Assembly id", BLANK(),
        "Can ship", 1,
        "Quantity per", 1
    ),
    FILTER( 'Item', NOT( 'Item'[Item id] IN ALL( 'BOM Component'[Component id] )))
)
Hierachical assemblies = 
UNION(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        'BOM Component',
        "Assembly id", 'BOM Component'[Assembly id],
        "Can ship", 'BOM Component'[Can ship],
        "Component description", 'BOM Component'[Component description],
        "Component id", 'BOM Component'[Component id],
        "Inventory", 'BOM Component'[Inventory],
        "Quantity per", 'BOM Component'[Quantity per]
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        'Missing assemblies',
        "Assembly id", 'Missing assemblies'[Assembly id],
        "Can ship", 'Missing assemblies'[Can ship],
        "Component description", 'Missing assemblies'[Description],
        "Component id", 'Missing assemblies'[Item id],
        "Inventory", 'Missing assemblies'[Inventory],
        "Quantity per", 'Missing assemblies'[Quantity per]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Blanks need to be replaced with *null* when using text columns inside PATH().